# ElementUI - How to Word wrap: break-word in el-table-column

Tags: javascript, css, element-ui

Using ElementUI I'd like to be able to wrap the text in a column on whitespace rather than in the middle of a word.  Normally you'd apply

```
white-space: normal;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

To the  in a normal column, or wrap in a div with that styling but when using ElementUI el-table and el-table-column it doesn't have any effect.  I've tried on the el-table-column as a class and as a direct applied style but nothing changes.

Does anyone have any experience of making this work?

Answer (score 11):

Inspect the element and check if the properties are correctly set.
Should be a problem of [CSS Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) from other parts of the library.

### Edit, solution

Try to put this CSS in a position that is after the CSS library, it should fix the problem.

```
.el-table .cell {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: I'd been through the shipped CSS and even changed it to include the values in the question but it's still not applied.  Hence asking for help

Comment: I'll dig into that, but at the moment I can't see a way to do it.  I've implemented that as a scoped style in my Vue component, as an unscoped style in the parent too, but it's getting overridden to break-all.  

If I use !important, it works but that feels too hacky to me.  I'll carry on experimenting.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, I see. I can't now install and try. An alternative approach should be won't fix the thing since in a tabular view data should stay in one line for readability. And changing the library classes without it has a way to do it is also a bad approach. IMHO